# Value vs Placeholder Attributes in HTML

Tags: php, html, input

I am working on a form, and have fields that may or may not be filled in by the user. To keep the backend logic simple, I plan on taking all the data from the form and updating my records with all of it, regardless of what the user has entered into the fields or not.

I was told (perhaps incorrectly) that I could take the data that currently exists in the database (ie, at the time the page loads) and put it into the input area's 'value' attribute. Supposedly, this would make it that if the user does NOT enter anything into the field, the old/current values will simply be passed back to the server and re-entered (but not changed).

If the user DOES enter data, then THAT would become the new value.

So it would look something like this:

```
<input type='text' name='XYZ' value='<?php echo $record['XYZ']; ?>'></td>
```

-1--So the first question is, is this true?

The second question is that I don't want this value showing up in the actual text field. Therefore, I added a placeholder attribute to the input tag:

```
<input type='text' name='XYZ' value='<?php echo $record['XYZ']; ?>' placeholder=''></td>
```

But the value attribute seems to override the placeholder tag!

-2--So the second Q is, is there anyway to assign the value as I would like and NOT have it appear in the actual textfield?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Well, yes. The `value` attribute defines what "is in the input field". It's the input field's *value*. There are three way to influence this value: type into the field, change it via Javascript, or set it via the HTML attribute. So if you pre-populate the value via the HTML attribute and then submit the form, that's the value that gets submitted back to your server.
2. The placeholder is the value that shows up as long as the actual value is empty. It's for giving the user a hint as to what they're supposed to enter into the field; once the user does enter something or the field is otherwise populated (see above), the placeholder is no longer needed.

You'll have to decide what it is you're trying to do exactly. Say you have a user's profile page where the user can update their information, in this case I'd very much prefer to have all my current information filled in and being able to change it. I don't want blank field, it doesn't make sense from a usability perspective.

If you really do want blank fields and only update information in the database for which the user has filled in the fields, the most useful technique is probably to simply only update those fields which the user filled in:

```
// only these fields may be submitted
$allowedFields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

// protecting from invalid submitted data, simplifies SQL injection prevention
if (array_diff(array_keys($_POST), $allowedFields)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid data submitted');
}

// filter out fields which do not have any input
$data = array_filter($_POST, 'strlen');

// prepare placeholders for binding data
$placeholders = array_map(
    function ($key) { return "`$key` = :$key"; }
    array_keys($data)
);

// prepare your query
$query = sprintf('UPDATE table SET %s WHERE id = :id', join(', ', $placeholders));
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);

$data['id'] = /* some id you get from somewhere to know what record to update */;

$stmt->execute($data);
```

The above is an example that assumes PDO as the database adaptor, change it as required for your own needs. It demonstrates though that it's pretty trivial to write dynamic updates which only update the columns which were submitted; you don't need to do special tricks with form data.

Answer (score 3):

The first part is correct; you can preset the value of an input field by using the "value" attribute, as in your first example. It is very common and a well-understood part of how the web works.

The placeholder text, although it appears in the same place as the value, is *not* a value. It is never submitted, and only shows up if there is no value.

What you're describing is possible, using javascript. But it is strange, unexpected behavior, and potentially confusing to users. Having the values pre-filled in the form communicates to the user: "You can change this, but this is what will be sent if you don't." It's usually a good idea to stick to established convention.

That said, one way to do it would be to use javascript. You could have all of the "real" input fields hidden, so that your pre-populated fields were invisible to the user.  Then, you could have unnamed 'dummy' fields, that are labeled to correspond the real fields.  When a user enters something in one of the dummy fields, you can use scripting to copy the value to its hidden partner, overwriting the preset value.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<input id="dummy_name" type="text"    placeholder="Enter your name">
<!-- no name, there, notice: it won't be submitted -->
<input id="real_name"  type="hidden"  name="name" value="Default">
```

JQuery:

```
$('#dummy_name').change(function(){
  var user_input = $('#dummy_name').val(); // get the user input
  $('#real_name').val(user_input);         // overwrite the value of the hidden field
});
```

or in plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('dummy_name').onchange=function(){
    var user_input = document.getElementById('dummy_name').value();
    document.getElementById('real_name').value = user_input;
};
```

If you went this route, you might also want to store the default value in a variable, so that it could be restored to the hidden field if they type something, but then clear it out. But all this is strongly discouraged, unless you have a good reason!

This solution is back-end agnostic, but as deceze suggests, this is perhaps better handled on the server side.

Comment: tnx for the help and advice!

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the `value` attribute specifies an initial (default) value for an `input` field. (For a `textarea`, you would use the content of the element instead.) And yes, the `placeholder` attribute value is shown only when the field has no value assigned; it is supposed to be a hint of the expected input.
2. In order to set a value for a field invisibly, use `type=hidden`:

   ```
   <input type='hidden' name='XYZ' value='<?php echo $record['XYZ']; ?>'>
   ```

   However, the user then cannot change the value in any normal means. You can include an `input` element with the same `name` attribute, too, but then you have the problem that the submitted data may contain two entries, and how can you decide which one of them is correct? Well, you can use different `name` attributes, e.g.

   ```
   <input type='hidden' name='XYZ-default' value='<?php echo $record['XYZ']; ?>'>
   <input type='text' name='XYZ'>
   ```

   Then your form data processing just has to check whether `XYZ` data is present and if not, use `XYZ-default` data instead.

   However, the goal sounds like poor usability. You are asking the user to input something, and it has a default value, but you are not telling the user what it is. So you might force the user to enter some data that you already have.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `@if` with two input like this:

```
if empty value show placeholder
else show value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with deceze that the user would probably find it helpful to see the information they're submitting.

I'm currently working with jQuery and Javascript, not PHP, so while I don't know the capabilities of PHP and its associated tools, I do know that jQuery has a way of changing the value of the placeholder dynamically; I'd be very surprised if that was something that wasn't shared with the language and tools that you're using.

Going along the lines of users seeing what they're submitting, you could always keep the placeholder up to date with what's being submitted. That way they could write over it if they wanted to change it, but still see what's going in if they don't. And if you can make it only update when the input tag's value is changed--rather than just replacing the placeholder with the back-end stored information every time--the extra resources it would use would be minimal as well. You'd also be able to reference the placeholder for the older values if you really wanted to keep things simple, like you've requested, but unless you're new or special circumstances are apparent, this is an inefficient way to do it.

This is of course a compromise from your asking for something the user wouldn't see. If you're set on old information being invisible, then this won't be helpful, but even though this is a couple years old I figured I'd throw the suggestion. After all, there may be some people coming here who are relatively new to these concepts that might find some use from it as well. I know it's something I would have appreciated.

Also, in a further response to your second question, there are now ways to add data to html elements that don't affect their performance or normal behavior. The link I found this with is for Javascript, but again, I would imagine crossing the language barrier would be relatively simple, especially with Google.

I believe this only works with HTML5, and not with XHTML. But hopefully it's helpful. Just keep in mind that having the data stored in the back-end (in your PHP code) will be faster than referencing these values back and forth. I believe that is mentioned in this link. I think that should only really matter for larger-scale projects, so if you're looking for efficiency this shouldn't be your first method of choice, but you may find yourself in a position where it's much simpler to take advantage of it.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/